# Как сделать текст постепенно прозрачным ,

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот нужно сделать что текст плавно затухал , вручную писать опасити каждый раз глупо ? Есть какой то скрипт может ?

Comment: Что вы попробовали? Приведите код, который вы написали. Уточните, что именно не получилось.

Comment: то что я написал работает , просто я каждое слово брал в SPAN тег , и указывал opacity , это работает , но это долго , можно ли написать скрипт который будет обходить слова в строке и задавать opacity каждому слову , от 100 до 0 равномерно

Comment: Можно в :after засунуть linear-gradient, от прозрачного уводящий в цвет фона. Это будет по факту не прозрачность, но выглядеть будет как она. И код/разметку надо текстом прикладывать, а не скриншотами.

Answer (score 0):

Вы указали метку JavaScript. Но в самом вопросе не привели никакого кода JavaScript, их чего я заключаю, что вы не знаете, **с чего начать**.

Представьте, что у вас текст в переменной. Первый этап: **разбейте текст на слова**. Причем сначала можете сделать кое-как, представив что слово, это текст между пробелами – потом можете продумать более сложный и грамматически правильный механизм.

После того как разбили текст на слова, у вас получился массив. Этот массив нужно как-то передалась в тот HTML, который нужен вам. **Функция [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** даёт коллбаку не только сам элемент (в нашем случае слово), но и индекс. Это нам очень даже понадобится.

И так, чтобы **посчитать процент opacity**, вам нужно поделить разницу между длиной массива и индексом на длину массива: opacity = (length - index) / length.

С помощью [шаблонных строк](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), вы **стоите ваш span**, с нужными значениями opacity и самого текста.

В результате, у вас массив, который содержит HTML, один span на элемент массива. **Склеиваете всё** это в один string. Вот и всё.

Comment: Спасибо , Java знаю , в JS еще только начинаю разбиратся ) 
Но звучит просто

Comment: `paragraph.innerHTML = paragraph.textContent.split(' ').map((w,i,arr)=>\`<span style="opacity:${(arr.length-i)/arr.length}">${w} </span>\`).join('');` - все работает, хороший ответ! Может и код добавить стоит))

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрев лишь на первый скрин, мне показалось, что текст разбит на предложения и "затухает" с каждым новым предложением.
И я изначально написал код с этим условием ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

```js
const par = document.querySelectorAll('.par');

par.forEach(function(e) {
  let self = e,
      text = self.innerText.trim(),
      offers = text.replace(/([.!?\r\n]+)/gm, '$1|||').split('|||');
  
  self.innerHTML = '';
  offers.forEach(function(e, i) {
    let span = document.createElement('span');
    span.style.opacity = 1 - (i / offers.length);
    span.innerText = offers[i];
    self.append(span);
  });
});
```

```css
.par:first-letter {
  font-size: 150%;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<p class="par">Допустим какое-то предложение. Или может такое? А что если, а хотя нет... А давай с новой строки! Всё, с новой строки.<br>Хлобысь<br>Новая строка</p>

<p class="par"></p>

<p class="par">Текст без знаков</p>
```

---

А вот аналогичная механика, но разбитие и "затухание" будет уже по словам.

```js
const par = document.querySelectorAll('.par');

par.forEach(function(e) {
  let self = e,
      text = self.innerText.trim(),
      offers = text.replace(/(\s+)/gm, '$1|||').split('|||');
  
  self.innerHTML = '';
  offers.forEach(function(e, i) {
    let span = document.createElement('span');
    span.style.opacity = 1 - (i / offers.length);
    span.innerText = offers[i];
    self.append(span);
  });
});
```

```css
.par:first-letter {
  font-size: 150%;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<p class="par">Допустим какое-то предложение. Или может такое? А что если, а хотя нет... А давай с новой строки! Всё, с новой строки.<br>Хлобысь<br>Новая строка</p>

<p class="par"></p>

<p class="par">Текст без знаков</p>
```

---

Основной момент заключается в разбитие, тут используется вот такой код

```
text.replace(/(\s+)/gm, '$1|||').split('|||');
```

Сначала он находит фрагмент по регулярке, в примере выше - `\s` (соответствует любому символу пробела, табуляции или новой строки.), заменяет его в тексте на `\s|||`, а потом полученный текст разделяет через `.split('|||')`.
Такой способ мне показался самым удачным, ибо все регулярки или разделения "сжирали" знаки препинания или переносы строк, а данный пример "сжирает" только то, что сам создал и при разделение сохраняет текст в первоначальном виде.